# Loading Javascript Object that contains gifs into HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have an object that contains video information(titles, links), all which I plan to use, including gif src links that become appended to a HTML element `<div id="videos"></div>`. My code works, see below, but what is happening is that since I have 8 different gifs running at the same time ,actually 46 but for the sake of this example i'm only using 8, the page is continuously loading it seems which eventually crashes.

**Questions:**

Should I use ajax to load this information?

Is my current object formatted properly to be used with ajax?

If I'm using ajax and once all the gifs are loaded, hopefully all 46, will the page come stop loading, preventing it from crashing hopefully.

I'm learning as I'm going so any best practices or industry standards for this type of functionality would be greatly appreciated!

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vkopw4kn/23/) - this one only has 3 videos because the 8 that i had kept crashing the fiddle window - I originally had 46, which caused the page to crash immediately!

**JavaScript Code**

```
var dataCollection = {
    'videoData': [
      {
        'id'      : 0,
        'title'   : 'Badminton',
        'company' : 'Pepto Bismol',
        'gifLink' : 'http://reneinla.com/kris/gifs/BadmintonPeptoBismolCommercial.gif',
        'srcMp4'  : 'http://reneinla.com/kris/videos/BadmintonPeptoBismolCommercial.m4v',
        'srcWebm' : 'http://reneinla.com/kris/videos/BadmintonPeptoBismolCommercial.webm',
        'srcOgv'  : 'http://reneinla.com/kris/videos/BadmintonPeptoBismolCommercial.ogv',
        'poster'  : 'http://reneinla.com/kris/videos/BadmintonPeptoBismolCommercial.jpg'
      },
      {
        'id'      : 1,
        'title'   : 'Home Brewer',
        'company' : 'Buffalo Wild Wings',
        'gifLink' : 'http://reneinla.com/kris/gifs/BuffaloWildWingsHomeBrewer.gif',
        'srcMp4'  : 'http://reneinla.com/kris/videos/BuffaloWildWingsHomeBrewer.m4v',
        'srcWebm' : 'http://reneinla.com/kris/videos/BuffaloWildWingsHomeBrewer.webm',
        'srcOgv'  : 'http://reneinla.com/kris/videos/BuffaloWildWingsHomeBrewer.ogv',
        'poster'  : 'http://reneinla.com/kris/videos/BuffaloWildWingsHomeBrewer.jpg'
      },
      {
        'id'      : 2,
        'title'   : 'Directly to Fabulous',
        'company' : 'California Lottery',
        'gifLink' : 'http://reneinla.com/kris/gifs/CaliforniaLottoMonopolyGoDirectlytoFabulous.gif',
        'srcMp4'  : 'http://reneinla.com/kris/videos/CaliforniaLottoMonopolyGoDirectlytoFabulous.m4v',
        'srcWebm' : 'http://reneinla.com/kris/videos/CaliforniaLottoMonopolyGoDirectlytoFabulous.webm',
        'srcOgv'  : 'http://reneinla.com/kris/videos/CaliforniaLottoMonopolyGoDirectlytoFabulous.ogv',
            'poster'  : 'http://reneinla.com/kris/videos/CaliforniaLottoMonopolyGoDirectlytoFabulous.jpg'
      }
    ]
};

$(function() {
  var videos = $('#video');
    for (var i = 0; i < dataCollection.videoData.length; i++) {
    var obj = dataCollection.videoData[i];
    //console.log(obj.gifLink);
    videos.append('<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 video-thumbs"><img src="' + obj.gifLink + '"/></div>');
  }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container row">
   <div id="videos"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your gif is quite too big, the first one in your fiddle has 100MB and others have around 50-60 MB. And In my experience Chrome tab crashed when a it's own memory usage is above a certain amount.

Comment: @fuyushimoya - that would make sense why the page keeps crashing...i didnt consider the size of the file. I feel like the browser should be able to handle it regardless...Is there a way to measure how much the browser is using up memory-wise (i'm assuming its memory?)

Comment: If you're using chrome, `shift+esc` would open a window to tell you how each page's cpu loading and how much mem they're using.

Comment: @fuyushimoya - thank you!